# Azcopy copy - Exclude a folder and the files inside it

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I want to copy all the folders and files in the Drive H: except the folder 'Recent'. The 'Recent' folder has multiple files and folders in it.

[The Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) has `--exclude-path`, but says cannot include wild characters. So will below code achieve the objective of copying all files and folders barring one directory ?

`azcopy cp 'H:\*' 'https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/folderA?saskey' --exclude-path 'H:\Recent ' --recursive`

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude-path for sync is now in 10.3.3
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/356

**Example Syntax**

```
"https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-01-01T16:07:51Z&st=2019-01-01T08:07:51Z&spr=https&sig=SIG" --exclude-path f1;f2 f3;f4
```

refer- https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/796

Answer (score 0):

This works in Linux and using Managed Identity:

```
azcopy login --identity

azcopy cp "/dir" "https://sa0xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/" > "/dir/path/blob-journal" --exclude-path="dir name" --recursive
```